# Changing default sort arrows of CMFCListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc

I found a problem. I can't change default sort arrows in header of `CMFCListCtrl`.
I found post on msdn about `CMFCHeaderCtrl::OnDrawSortArrow` but it didn't help because no examples there.

I tried simple method how I set arrows to `CListCtrl` header through the `CimageList` and `HDITEM` but those arrow sets only to left side because right side has already arrow default.

Google is empty on solutions how change default arrows on `CMFCListCTrl`.

Please help me)
Thanks!
PS. Please note that this is `CMFCListCtrl` not a `CListCtrl` where I can add arrows very easly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because CMFCHeaderCtrl is a member inside CMFCListCtrl you can not overwrite it.
Try to derive yor own CMFCListCtrl class, with your own CMFCHeaderCtrl class, that overwrites <s>OnDrawSortHeader</s> OnDrawSortArrow.
Overwrite CMFCListCtrl::InitHeader and subclass to your header control class.

If you start form scratch with a CListCtrl you can directly subclass the header control. The complete stuff inside CMFCListCtrl isn't so complicated and easy to reimplement. Depends what functionality you need.

Comment: xMRi thanks a lot for posting. I fight with this a few days(
Nobody can help and no solutions in google(
But how can I draw a arrow from Bitmap or HICON in OnDrawSortArrow

PS. Did you mean OndrawSortArrow instead OnDrawSortHeader?

Comment: oooh! I have a small question. Do you know a style of header in CListCtrl? In CMFCListCtrl is another style of header. Is it possible to change CMFCListCtrl style of header on CListCtrl style of header?
And thanks again MR)

Comment: Yes you can. :) Look into the current implementation. You have a DC and a rectangle. draw whatever you like. The current visual manager draws the arrows with MoveTo/LineTo

Comment: OK thank you) you shown me a way
I will check your question like best solution.
But I would like to ask you about some simple sample how drawing in context if you have already some image in Bitmap or HICON itc, surely if you have something under hand)
Tanks again)

Comment: May be the easiest way is to use a CImageList for drawing the symbols. Otherwise just use DrawIcon if you have an icon...

Comment: DrawIcon looks good:)
I will be try it)
Thanks a lot and even more more more)!

Answer (score 0):

The CMFCHeaderCtrl calls the currently active Visual Manager to do the actual drawing of sort arrows. It is easy to implement a customized Visual manager which overrides the arrow drawing method in the base class.

```
class CMyVisualManager:public CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007
{
    virtual void OnDrawHeaderCtrlSortArrow(CMFCHeaderCtrl* pCtrl, CDC* pDC, CRect& rect, BOOL bIsUp);
};


void CMyVisualManager::OnDrawHeaderCtrlSortArrow(CMFCHeaderCtrl* pCtrl, CDC* pDC, CRect& rectArrow, BOOL bIsUp)
{
   BOOL bDlgCtrl = pCtrl->IsDialogControl();

   CPen penDark(PS_SOLID, 1, bDlgCtrl ? afxGlobalData.clrBtnDkShadow : afxGlobalData.clrBarDkShadow);

   CPen* pPenOld = pDC->SelectObject(&penDark);;
   ASSERT_VALID(pPenOld);

   if (!bIsUp)
   {
      pDC->MoveTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x, rectArrow.bottom);
      pDC->LineTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x, rectArrow.top);

      pDC->MoveTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x-2, rectArrow.top+4);
      pDC->LineTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x+3, rectArrow.top+4);

      pDC->MoveTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x-1, rectArrow.top+3);
      pDC->LineTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x+2, rectArrow.top+3);
      pDC->MoveTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x-1, rectArrow.top+2);
      pDC->LineTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x+2, rectArrow.top+2);
   }
   else
   {
      pDC->MoveTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x, rectArrow.top);
      pDC->LineTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x, rectArrow.bottom);

      pDC->MoveTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x-2, rectArrow.bottom-4);
      pDC->LineTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x+3, rectArrow.bottom-4);

      pDC->MoveTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x-1, rectArrow.bottom-3);
      pDC->LineTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x+2, rectArrow.bottom-3);
      pDC->MoveTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x-1, rectArrow.bottom-2);
      pDC->LineTo(rectArrow.CenterPoint().x+2, rectArrow.bottom-2);
   }

   pDC->SelectObject(pPenOld);
}
```